# Как сделать скрытое перенаправление с домена на хостинг без фрейма и без изменения url?

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

Есть домен http://franziska-kimme.de  и другой хостинг.
Проблема в том, что введя доменное имя в компании есть только либо перенаправление прямое, но тогда url меняется, либо непрямое с [franziska-kimme.de](http://franziska-kimme.de) на нужный хостинг, но все данные во фрейме. Тоесть я открываю домен, а он подставляет фрейм с адресом моего хостинга - выходит полная ж---а.
Индексации нол,метатегов ноль(они все во фрейме)- короче бред. Техподдержка явно так и не сказала, что делать, что б иметь доменный url и загрузить данные с хостинга "как есть" без всяких фреймов. Как-то через DNS.
Кто-то может подсказать, что делать надо?Бо гугл напрочь не индексирует вообще. И фрейм в сайте-это в данном случае бред полный